# an Ajax.ActionLink fired only the first time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have an ActionLink in my view. When clicked, an action in my controller is fired (I placed a breakpoint to check). It works only the first time the link is clicked. Other times, the breakpoint in my action controller is never reached.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Remove image", "RemoveImage", new { projectID = Model.ProjectID }, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess="ImageRemovedSuccess" })
```

The function "ImageRemovedSuccess" for the OnSuccess ajax event is well fired but the action in the controller is not fired.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your browser caches the response. So the second time when you send the request browser will not forward it to the server because the same request was sent to the server before and the browser will return the cached response to the page.

Decorate the action method not to cache the response in between.

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult RemoveImage(int projectID)
    {

    }
```

Make sure you press "Ctrl + F5" on the browser before you check it.

Comment: +1 For pointing me to the solution I needed, but this doesn't work with Partial views, so I've added an additional answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Additional answer for Partial Views (only)

Partial views don't like the settings `NoStore` or a `Duration` of 0.

You get `Additional information: OutputCacheAttribute for child actions only supports Duration, VaryByCustom, and VaryByParam values. Please do not set CacheProfile, Location, NoStore, SqlDependency, VaryByContentEncoding, or VaryByHeader values for child actions.` for `NoStore` and another error that `Duration must be positive` if you set `Duration=0`

The fix for Partial views (compatible with the normal views) is:

```
   [OutputCache(Duration = 1, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

This caches for a maximum of one second, which should be fine for normal operations.